# How to get variables from my .env file to the Azure Pipeline

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure-devops, gulp, azure-pipelines

When I build my react app locally, all the envoriment variables get read from my local .env file, which is inside the projects root folder. We use gulp for the building process.
Now i want the same variables available in my azure pipeline, which also builds the app via gulp and deploys it to my Azure Static Web App.

I already tried pushing my .env file to the repo and also tried to set these variables in the pipelines YAML file via

```
env:
  HOSTNAME: 'google.com'
```

And I also tried putting the values in my pipelines variables and accessing it in YAML like

```
env:
  HOSTNAME: $(HOSTNAME)
```

Lastly I tried uploading my .env to Devops Pipelines Secure files, then adding Tasks to my pipeline to access this file and copiying it to my repos root folder.

All ways ended up with just random String like "8a8878aa1317" inside this variables, once the app is deployed and running. This random strings changes each time I run the pipeline. Does anyone know how to get the right values to the variables?

Comment: Hi @Bryan, Have you tried reading the variables in the pipeline through a PowerShell task that will scan you `.ENV` file and make available the variables from the same

Comment: `HOSTNAME` is a tricky name, because it might be used by underlying OS or DevOps Agent (a random string value suggests that). Try changing it to something like `MY_HOSTNAME` (in .env file, in the pipeline and in your app) and see if that works.

Comment: @qbik This was actually the problem ... thank you so much sir! I changed HOSTNAME to something like MY_HOSTNAME and now its getting the right value. If you can post your comment as an answer I will approve it! Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HOSTNAME` is a tricky name for a variable, because it might be used by underlying OS or DevOps Agent (a random string value suggests that).

Try changing it to something like `MY_HOSTNAME` (in `.env` file, in the pipeline and in your app).